# How do I choose the appropriate numbers of customers to be considered for cluster analysis?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, sas

I am currently doing a customer segmentation project in SAS.

I have identified 2700 customers who are have made a purchase in each of the 4 years I am analysing. For the cluster analysis the more purchases/customer each year the better the data quality is. However as I become more selective over number of purchases needed each year per customer, the less customers can be considered in the cluster analysis.

How should I go about choosing the cutoff point for the number of purchases necessary per customer per year to be considered for analysis. I am struggling with this trade off between data quality and having enough customers for analysis.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I wonder if number of purchases might be one of the most important variables for the customer segmentation (at least from a business point of view).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to limit this?

If you only have 2,700 customers there's nothing preventing you from analyzing all of them. In that case, the number of purchases per year might - as @gung points out - be a rather significant variable